# Presence-absence matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to generate a presence-absence matrix grid based on the example code from the `letsR` package and `lets.presab.points()` function.

Example code:

```
species <- c(rep("sp1", 100), rep("sp2", 100),
             rep("sp3", 100), rep("sp4", 100))
x <- runif(400, min = -69, max = -51)
y <- runif(400, min = -23, max = -4)
xy <- cbind(x, y)
PAM <- lets.presab.points(xy, species, xmn = -93, xmx = -29, 
                          ymn = -57, ymx = 15)
summary(PAM)
```

My code:

```
records <- read.csv("directoryremovedforprivacy.csv")
x <- records$lon
y <- records$lat
xy <- cbind(x, y)
PAM2 <- lets.presab.points(xy, records, xmn = -11.5, xmx = 3,
                          ymn = 49, ymx = 61)
summary(PAM2)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in xy[pos, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
> summary(PAM2)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object 'PAM2' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, the issue is probably with `records` in `lets.presab.points`. It expects a list of species, but you are trying to give it a dataframe. So, in your example code, `species` is a character vector, so it needs to be the same format for your code too. So, you might need to do something like this (although I'm uncertain what the format of your `records` data is):

```
library(letsR)

PAM2 <- lets.presab.points(xy, records$species, xmn = -11.5, xmx = 3,
                          ymn = 49, ymx = 61)
```

`species` needs to be the same length as `xy`.